# Error when running EF migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I just created a new web project for .net core 2.0 preview 1 which includes Individual User Accounts authentication using visual studio 2017 preview edition.

Then when I tried to run update-database from Package Manager Console, I got the following error message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. For information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054. ---> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: No certificate named 'HTTPS' found in configuration for the current environment (Production).
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.CertificateLoader.LoadSingle(String certificateName)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.CertificateLoader.Load(IConfigurationSection certificateConfiguration)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.KestrelServerOptionsSetup.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<BindEndPoint>b__0(ListenOptions listenOptions)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.KestrelServerOptionsSetup.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<BindEndPoint>b__0(ListenOptions listenOptions)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerOptions.Listen(IPEndPoint endPoint, Action`1 configure)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerOptions.Listen(IPAddress address, Int32 port, Action`1 configure)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.KestrelServerOptionsSetup.BindEndPoint(KestrelServerOptions options, IConfigurationSection endPoint, CertificateLoader certificateLoader)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.KestrelServerOptionsSetup.BindConfiguration(KestrelServerOptions options)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.KestrelServerOptionsSetup.Configure(KestrelServerOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.LegacyOptionsCache`1.CreateOptions()
   at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T](T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.LegacyOptionsCache`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.CreateServiceContext(IOptions`1 options, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer..ctor(IOptions`1 options, ITransportFactory transportFactory, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite singletonCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureServer()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   at Test.Program.BuildWebHost(String[] args) in     C:\Users\Test\Documents\Test\src\Test\Program.cs:line 21
   at Test.Identity.Data.IdentityServiceDbContextFactory.Create(String[] args) in C:\Users\Test\Documents\Test\src\Test\Areas\IdentityService\Data\IdentityServiceDbContextFactory.cs:line 13
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<FindContextTypes>b__3()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. For information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.
```

The same error also occur when I run it from cmd.

How can I fix this to run the migration successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using .NET Core 2.0 Preview 1 when this problem occurs. Even after following some suggestions which seems to be a way to solve this in the following link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/security/https, I still got the same error.

At the end I decided to to upgrade to .NET Core 2.0 Preview 2 and now it works like a charm :)

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/06/28/announcing-net-core-2-0-preview-2/